# Convert Anonymous Type to List <T> using Linq to SQL in C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with MVC 4 with Linq to SQL and in my controller class I intend to obtain a List from a query that has several tables and show it into the view as a List where M is a model class:

In the controller I have this

```
 public List<HomeViewModel> GetHomeViewModel()
    {
        dynamic ReservationDay = (from c in hutRes.Clients
                              join r in hutRes.Reservations on c.ID_Client equals r.FK_Client
                              join ht in hutRes.Hut_Types on r.FK_HutType equals ht.ID_Hut_Type
                              join tr in hutRes.Time_Reserves on r.FK_TimeReserve equals tr.ID_Time_Reserve
                              join tc in hutRes.Type_ClientIds on c.FK_TypeClientId equals tc.ID_Type_ClientId
                              where r.DateR == DateTime.Now
                              select new
                              {
                                  r.ID_Reservation,
                                  tc.ClientId,
                                  Number = c.Number_ID,
                                  c.Name,
                                  c.Phone,
                                  time = tr.TimeReserve,
                                  ReservationDate = r.DateR
                              }).ToList();

        return ReservationDay;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(GetHomeViewModel());
    }
```

And in the view side I have this header:

```
@model List<HutReservation.ViewModel.HomeViewModel>
```

I'm having this error:

```
Can not implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType4 <int,string,short,string,string,string,System.DateTime,byte,string,short,string,string>>' in 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HutReservation.ViewModel.HomeViewModel>'
```

Can Anybody help me I'm really stuck here :(

Comment: Sorrymy error means:
Can not implicity convert type: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType4<int,string,short,string,string,string,System.DateTime,byte,string,short,string,string>>' in 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HutReservation.ViewModel.HomeViewModel>'

Comment: What is the reason of creating anonymous type instead of `HomeViewModel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Anonymous type in LINQ use:

```
select new HomeViewModel 
{
// Set class variables here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a list of your anonymous type can't be converted to a list of `HomeViewModel`.

Why are you using an anonymous type, anyway? Simply create a new `HomeViewModel` instance in your query (`Select` a `HomeViewModel` instead of an anonymous type).